# C++ static variable in .lib does not initialize

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, static-libraries, static-members

I have static library (.lib) in VS2010 and am linking it to my test project.

The lib has a factory that I create using the below MACRO:

```
#define REGISTER_FACTORY(mType, my_class) \
class Factory##my_class : public CAbstractFactory\
{\
public:\
    Factory##my_class() : CAbstractFactory(mType){}\
    CBaseClass *Create()\
    { return new my_class(); }\
};\
static Factory##my_class StaticFactory##my_class;
```

What is supposed to happen is that in the CAbstractFactory the new factory gets registered by `mtype`. But when I check the factory the factory does not exist.

It works fine when I use a DLL instead of a .lib. My guess is that the linker does not include the static variable as it is not referenced or the static variable was not even included in the library.

How can I force the linker to include all objects from the static library in my .exe.

I use the macro like this:

```
// Register factory that can create CMyObject with ID=100
REGISTER_FACTORY(100, CMyObject);

class CMyObject
{
};
```

The CAbstractFactory looks like this:

```
class CAbstractFactory {
    CAbstractFactory(int id) {
        CFactory::instance().add(id, this);
    }
}
```

Then some where else in the code, my main .exe I use:

```
CBaseClass *pObject = CFactory::instance().Create(100);
```

This will then give my a new `CMyObject`. The idea is that I have many different kind object and I have a database containing the id specifying the kind of objects I need.
`100` is just an example.

So indeed, I do not reference anything from the .lib directly but I want to be able to create the objects using my factory

The CFactory class is a simple class that keeps a register (in a map) of all the CAbstractFactory classes and delegates the create method to the correct factory.

```
CFactory &CFactory::Instance()
{
    static CFactory instance;
    return instance;
}
```

The main problem lies in the fact that I do not reference anything from the .lib as it is all done through the CFactory. It works if I make it a DLL and make sure I add some reference to this DLL to make sure it is loaded. But for a .lib, I even added a dummy function to make sure I have at least one reference that doesn't include the rest of the code.

Comment: This is only macro, I hope you use it somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I use it to create factories to a family of objects. I have added some more details.

Comment: Show the definition of `CFactory::instance()` (and anything that refers to). It looks like it might be returning a reference to a static object

Comment: Added the CFactory::instance(), it is indeed a static, but the CFactory lives in a different DLL.

Comment: "the CFactory lives in a different DLL" - oh. I'm not sure exactly how static objects in other DLLs are supposed to work, hopefully someone else can help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by setting the lib project as a dependency of the main app project and then setting 'Link Library Dependencies' and 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' to Yes for the main project.

---

Update:

Recently I discovered that Visual Studio 2015 now supports a `/WHOLEARCHIVE` linker flag.  I can't find it through the linker options, but you can add it as an additional command line option. It works similar to the GCC flag `-whole-archive` and you add it to your target linker flags (not to the static lib flags).

For example, specify `/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib_name` as an additional linker command line option and it will include all symbols from that lib. You can do this more than one lib as well.

If you use this `/WHOLEARCHIVE:lib_name` you no longer need the 'Link Library Dependencies' and 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' set to Yes.  This is perfect for solutions generated through CMAKE. See a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42083877/1151329

Comment: Now I have manually configure the .lib in the Input ` Additional Dependencies` and the path in the `Additional Library Directories`. I can access the dummy function from the .lib but the statics are not initialized. I also added the lib to the `Project Dependencies`. Should I do it differently?

Comment: Do you have the 'Linker->General->Link Library Dependencies' and 'Linker->General->Use Library Dependency Inputs' set to 'Yes' for your main app?

Comment: Got it. I manually linked the lib to the mainapp. I should have done this: MainProject->Properties->Common Properties->Framework and References and then add my Lib as a reference. That together with the options as you describe did the job!

Comment: Also check if you have 'Linker->Optimisation->References' set to 'No (/OPT:NOREF)'

Comment: Now see if I can get it to work using CMake as well ;)

Answer (score -1):

`static` defines an object with internal linkage --> if it's not used *internally* in the same translation unit, it can be optimized out. Remove the `static` from your instantiation for the object to have external linkage - `Factory##my_class StaticFactory##my_class;`

Comment: I don't want to link to the static directly. I wanted it to instantiate and registering itself with my factory.

Comment: @icepack The base class constructor makes a call to a function outside this unit, so that should prevent it being optimized out

Comment: @Matt McNabb, I read somewhere on the GoogleTest site that they warn about a bug in the VC++ compiler/linker that it indeed optimizes code out that should not be optimized out. I guess this is a real problem for test suites that rely on this mechanism a lot. See https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users