# How to avoid for c++ compiler optimizer to remove static variable code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, googletest, static-variables

I use C++ in MS Visual Studio C++ 2013 sp5.
As you know, google test(gtest) initialize test codes as static variables.
When I put these gtest codes (.cpp) in main project, there is no problem.
But, when I move these gtest codes (.cpp) to library project which main project depends, gtest don't work.
I can't put breakpoint as if there is no code. (BreakPoint point looks like white circle not red circle).
I guess compiler optimizer omit these static variables code in cpp because these variables are references nowhere. But, it's constructor do something so I don't understand why compiler remove or doesn't make code for these static variables.

How to prevent these situation?
Is there any options for that? Or any knowhow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797681/c-static-variable-in-lib-does-not-initialize

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599035/force-visual-studio-to-link-all-symbols-in-a-lib-file/32435026#32435026

Comment: I'll give these a shot.

Comment: Place a breakpoint. Ignore the fact that it's a white circle. Run the test. Does it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn 'Link Library Dependencies' and 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' into Yes then compiler make codes. It works.
[C++ static variable in .lib does not initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797681/c-static-variable-in-lib-does-not-initialize)
[force visual studio to link all symbols in a lib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599035/force-visual-studio-to-link-all-symbols-in-a-lib-file/32435026#32435026)