# How to set Visual-Studio LinkLibraryDependencies property to yes through CMAKE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cmake

When I generate a Visual Studio target with cmake, the generated project file contains the following in the platform properties section:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    ...
    <ProjectReference>
      <LinkLibraryDependencies>false</LinkLibraryDependencies>
    </ProjectReference>
    ...
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

I would like to set the property to true from the CMakeLists file. How do I do this?

My project dependencies are set up using `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`, but on Linux I can also use, for example:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${targetname} "-Wl,--whole-archive" *some libs* "-Wl,--no-whole-archive")
```

This forces all symbols to link into the target.

With visual studio the way to link all symbols is to specify:

```
<LinkLibraryDependencies>true</LinkLibraryDependencies>
```

through the project settings.

Comment: This smells strongly of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/201677). What do you want to achieve by setting this property to true? In CMake, you should express link dependencies using CMake (`target_link_libraries()`), not using generator-specific things which will not work with other generators (Makefiles etc.)

Comment: It is not for setting up dependencies. I do use target_link_libraries() for that. I will edit my question and add more detail.

Comment: You can't. See [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2011-April/013246.html): "In fact we purposely set LinkLibraryDependencies to false so that `add_dependencies` does NOT cause linking."

Comment: Are you **sure** that `LinkLibraryDependencies` causes all symbols to be linked? I'm 99% certain that's not the case.

Comment: See one of my SO answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799529/1151329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the 'Link Library Dependencies' and 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' flags are no longer required to link all lib symbols.

In Visual Studio 2015 you can no use the `/WHOLEARCHIVE` linker flag on the target. I edited my answer to a related question to give more detail on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23799529/1151329

The flag works like the GCC `-whole-archive` linker flag.

In my CMAKE file I added this:

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${targetname} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "/WHOLEARCHIVE:debug_lib_name")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${targetname} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "/WHOLEARCHIVE:release_lib_name")
```